# sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc, peer, grpc-node

Hell everyone, I am trying to setup a multi-org hyperledger fabric network and I run it already successfully. But when I tried to connect using Node SDK to fabric network to get some data. I am facing below error, I suspect that it is because of the tls cert file but I dont exactly know whats the problem. Hope someone can help me on this. See below details:

Error:
[image]

```
var peer = fabric_client.newPeer(
            'grpcs://localhost:7051', {
                'pem': 'somepath/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem'
            });
        channel.addPeer(peer);
```